# Close button of CCommanBar does not exit the application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-mobile

I am creating a smart device application, that creates a command bar this way:

```
if (!m_wndCommandBar.Create(this) ||
        !m_wndCommandBar.InsertMenuBar(IDR_MAINFRAME) ||
        !m_wndCommandBar.AddAdornments(dwAdornmentFlags))
    {
        TRACE0("CommandBar no se pudo crear\n");
        return -1;      // No se pudo crear
    }

    m_wndCommandBar.SetBarStyle(m_wndCommandBar.GetBarStyle() | CBRS_SIZE_FIXED);
```

That way, a command bar is created with a close button.

This is a SDI application for smart device.

When I press the close button, the application window disappear, but application continues running. I realized about that because when I debug using Visual Studio 2008, the debugger does not finish.

What can I do?

Comment: Show us the code how so you add the close button and how du you exit the application.

Comment: That's the problem. I have not added that button. System add some buttons automatically (start button, sip button and close button). I realized that the close button only hides the application, because I can see it in task manager. I have only added my own IDR_MAINFRAME menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default buttons and system controls on Windows Mobile do not close but hide (minimize) the window. So the app keeps running in the background.

You need to add custom code to end your app. You may do this for example with a seprate button or menu item and then execute PostQuitMessage or other code to end the main process (after terminating any created background threads).

You may also modify the Window Style to include a Close (OK) button.

```
CommandBar_AddAdornments(hwnCB, 0, 0);
```

adds standard commandbar controls, normally a Close (X) and Help option. You can use the CMDBAR_OK flag for the above call to add a Exit/End (OK) button. Your message loop will get a WM_COMMAND message with IDOK as message ID. That can be used to Exit the app with PostQuitMessage(). See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wt26z0c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

For your code:

```
 m_wndCommandBar.AddAdornments(dwAdornmentFlags))
```

can be changed to:

```
 m_wndCommandBar.AddAdornments(dwAdornmentFlags || CMDBAR_OK))
```

Comment: I have added an OK button instead and by controlling WM_COMMAND I could post a quit message so the app terminates, calling all classes' destructors to free the memory. All is fine now  I will try to change the OK text to other text or icon. I hope it is possible.

Comment: You can not change the OK if you use CMDBAR_OK. Windows Mobile is very restrictive.